# How do you style an android app?

Tags: android, css, styling, look-and-feel

I've been doing web development for some time, and now I want do learn android. I know java and that is fine. What interests me is how do I style my app. For example if I would like to put some border on my button, or add a shadow. If it was an web site I would use css, but what do I use in android ?

I'm talking about native android apps, and I would not like to use a framework like ionic or someting similar.

Comment: As a "Programing Language" you use `XML`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android has own styles system thought properties.
It's a little similar with css.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
android:typeface="monospace"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

You can read more in 
[official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)